# how to fix the admin bug in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I created a snippet model and registered an admin to this model and created a form to add records of this model, but when clicking the snippet button on the admin page, it takes me to the form I have created.
This is my views method:

```
def snippet(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = SnippetForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
form = SnippetForm()
return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})
```

This is my form.py:

```
class SnippetForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Snippet
    fields = ('name', 'body')
```

And this is my models.py

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
body = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the form is saved, you should return from there, otherwise

```
form = SnippetForm()
return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})
```

will be executed and it will take you to the same page.

---

Change:

```
def snippet(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SnippetForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    form = SnippetForm()
    return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})
```

To:

```
def snippet(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SnippetForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(YOUR_SUCCESS_URL)    # You have to return from here.

    form = SnippetForm()
    return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Or if he use the same html on success (on edit action, for example), he can use `if not form: form = SnippetForm()` instead of `return redirect...`.

Comment: i tried your solution but nothing changed, every time i click on the snippets on the admin page it just takes me to the form i've created and when submitting nothing is added as a record to the database

Answer (score 0):

The last 2 lines of your view are always executed, you have to return (e.g. some  HttpResponseRedirect) after you do form.save()

```
def snippet(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SnippetForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Here you have to return and redirect where you want to
    form = SnippetForm()
    return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: i tried this solution to return HTTPResponse and Redirect but non of both worked and still hitting snippets on the admin page takes me to the form

Comment: Myapp
Snippets    Add    Change (this is from the admin page ) every time i click on the Snippets to see my records it takes me to the form

Comment: hold on, I don't quite understand, are you doing this in contrib.admin ? If you are using the django admin site, you need not write any view. YOu just have to register your model in the admin.py file